# Looping through VBA to find matches and inserting them without overwriting previous results

Tags: excel, vba

Typically I scan two different datasets/tables in excel on an ongoing basis against possible matches using the following simple VBA code which runs it against a range in Worksheet 2 (SecondaryTable) and Worksheet 1 (MainTable):

```
Sub loop()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim lCol2 As Long
Dim wordsArray() as Variant
wordsArray = Worksheets ("SecondaryTable").Range("A2:A" & lRow2).Value
Dim word As Variant
Dim cell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("MainTable")
Set sht2 = Worksheets("SecondaryTable")

lRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.RowsCount
lCol = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
lRow2 = sht2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
lCol2 = sht2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

For Each cell in Worksheets("MainTable").Range("I2:I" & lRow)
For Each word in wordsArray
if InStr(cell.Value, word)>0 Then
Cell.Offset (0, -2). Value = word
End if
Next Word
Next Cell

End Sub
```

The main issue I am facing currently is tied to a situation when more than one keyword is identified via the macro (e.g., two or three strings match the cell) which leads vba to overwrite the previous identified match. For example Table 2 might have dog, cat and apple that are part of wordsArray, hence a cell containing all of these values/strings in Table would only return one and overwrite the previous two. Is there any way of allowing VBA to keep all matches in the same cell?

Comment: `Cell.Offset (0, -2). Value = Cell.Offset (0, -2). Value & " " & word`

Comment: @CDP1802 Thank you for this solution, I was trying out something similar and your suggestion works like a charm. How do I mark your response as the answer btw?